# Factory::getDate('now', $this->app->get('offset'))->toSql() is losing timezone?

Tags: date, jfactory, format

Why is turning a date `->toSql` losing the timezone value?

```
var_dump(Factory::getDate('now', $this->app->get('offset'))->toSql());
```

> 2023-09-14 17:10:04

```
var_dump(Factory::getDate('now', $this->app->get('offset')));
```

> 2023-09-14 19:10:04.627966

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a flag, true or false, as to whether you want the local time or not in the toSql() function.

The comments for the toSql function explain what is required.

```
    /**
     * Gets the date as an SQL datetime string.
     *
     * @param   boolean         $local  True to return the date string in the local time zone, false to return it in GMT.
     ...
     */
    public function toSql($local = false, DatabaseDriver $db = null)
    {
        ...
        return $this->format($db->getDateFormat(), $local, false);
    }
```